Почему независимо от того какой инкремент употребляется в цикле for, результат получается один и тот же?
Пример 1:
<?php
$sum = 0; // при первом проходе запишется 1
$count = 0;
    for ($i= 1; $sum <= 1; ++$i) {
        $sum += $i;
        $count++;
    }
    echo $count;
?>

Пример 2:
<?php
$sum = 0; // при первом проходе запишется 1
$count = 0;
    for ($i= 1; $sum <= 1; $i++) {
        $sum += $i;
        $count++;
    }
    echo $count;
?>


А почему вы считаете что результат должен быть разным?

при префиксном инкременте результат сначала увеличится, а затем запишется. То есть, должно же быть как: при первом проходе, в 1 примере,  $i=2 и в $sum должно записаться 2, но пишется 1.

@Никита, это могло бы быть так, если бы ты использовал возвращаемое значение инкремента, а не обращался к уже увеличенному значению переменной. В этом случае не важно каким способом ты добавил единицу, если ты смотришь на конечное значение.

@Никита всё так. Но оба этих действия происходят ДО строчки $sum += $i. А в этой строчке у $i уже новое значение независимо от способа инкремента.

@AlexeyTen всё же, думаю, не ДО $sum, а ПОСЛЕ $count++. Разницы всё равно не видно, но правильнее именно второе

Разница инкрементов состоит в разных возвращаемых значениях
В коде из вопроса, возвращаемое значение инкремента не используется, поэтому и разницы в работе не видно.
Чтобы увидеть разницу, надо суммировать значение, которое возвращает оператор инкремента, а не значение переменной $i:
$sum = 0; 
$count = 0;
for ($i= 1; $sum <= 1; $sum += ++$i) {
    $count++;
}
echo "$count, $sum\n";

$sum = 0; 
$count = 0;
for ($i= 1; $sum <= 1; $sum += $i++) {
    $count++;
}
echo "$count, $sum\n";


Если прочесть документацию, то увидим, что цикл for схематично выглядит так:
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement

А выражение expr3 вычисляется (выполняется) только в конце каждой итерации. То есть после всех вычислений, которые находятся в фигурных скобках. Получается, что в данном случае это ни на что не влияет.

даже если поменять условие, чтобы было несколько итераций - результат все равно не будет отличаться каким бы видом инкремента не менялась переменная $i

Не понял к чему комментарий) Я вроде всё описал что должно)

И это никак не связано с тем, что спрашивается в вопросе ¯\(ツ)/¯ Не важно когда вычисляется expr3 - важно то, что результат выражения нигде не используется, а только при его использовании была бы разница.

Неправда. Вопрос об инкременте и декременте, но в рамках цикла for. И ответ вполне объясняет почему инкремент ни на что не влияет

Нет не объясняет.

После долгих размышлений я вынужден согласиться с Grundy. Я долго пытался присобачить сюда идею о том, что for может где-то использовать результат оператора, но потом убедился, что не может: он везде использует только значение переменной $i, и нигде, даже теоретически, не может использовать значение оператора. Так что да, его размещение ни на что не влияет. Извиняюсь за непоследовательность
